# Parameters needed to connect to a MySql Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

When I want to connect to Database using C# visual studio 2013, I provide the following parameters to the "connectionString" using "MySqlConnection":

```
string server="localhost";
string database="database123";
string uid = "*****";
string password = "******";
string port = "3306";
```

but I noticed that if I don't provide "database" or "port" it works fine too.
My question is what should one provide to establish a proper connection?
or What is considered sufficient info to establish a connection?

Comment: no db is sufficient. then a `use myDb`. but consider if it makes sense. Default port is 3306 for that driver. pretty much the default for anything, like sqlyog, mysql cmd line. There are a lot of mysql daemons running out there <>3306

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @DrewPierce So I guess it just uses the defaults when I don't provide it with what is needs... thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad -- what is "sufficient" for you might not be sufficient for anyone else. The only answer is "whatever is right for your specific application and needs." There are built-in defaults -- you don't even need to specify the server (defaults to `127.0.0.1`). There are fallbacks and defaults for most connection string parameters.

Comment: you are correct sir @ehab

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Thanks for your help, I agree with you

Answer (score -3):

I would use this.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=somthing; database=something; User ID=******; Password=******");
```

Comment: thanks @MZaragoza, I am Kind of new so I did not know how to write so it looked like that.

Comment: there are a couple of things you can do like pace 4 times, use the {} in the wysiwyg or you can use the "`" back ticks http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: **Thanks** I appreciate it.